# Call function without calling advice defined on it

Tags: functions, advice, funcall

I sometimes want to bypass the advice I have defined on some function. Something like:

```
(call-without-advice #'fn ...)
```

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible, but just for clarity what are the circumstances in which you want to call the original function only?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Temporarily remove it, after saving it, then restore it. [This page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicIsearchFiltering) and the code it describes might help a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find a public interface for that. In Emacs 25.5 and Emacs 27.1 and presumably every version in between (I haven't checked older or more recent versions), for new-style advice (`define-advice`, `advice-xxx` from `nadvice.el`), you can use

```
(advice--cd*r (symbol-function #'fn))
```

For old-style advice (`defadvice`, `ad-xxx` from `advice.el`):

```
(ad-get-orig-definition #'fn)
```

Answer (score 7):

I've thought about this before, and there's a less-than-perfect solution: 
you need to **store the original definition before any `advice-add`ing**.

```lisp
(defun f ()
  (insert "233\n"))

(setq f.backup (symbol-function 'f))

(advice-add 'f :around
            (lambda (fobj &rest args)
              (insert (format "eq?: %s\n"
                              (eq f.backup fobj)))
              (apply fobj args)))
```

It is also convenient to store the definition in symbol-plist.

---

###### Update

```lisp
(advice-add 'advice-add :before
            (lambda (symbol &rest _)
              (unless (get symbol :shynur/original-definition)
                (put symbol :shynur/original-definition
                     (symbol-function symbol)))))

(defun call-without-advice (symbol &rest arguments)
  (apply (or (get symbol :shynur/original-definition)
             symbol)
         arguments))
```

looks much better now.